# Frame shifted up / empty space between view frame and tab bar with tab bar translucent set to "NO"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

Here's my scenario:

I have a UITabBar that is using all the default settings and my app's tab bar translucency boolean is set to YES.

I wanted to change the colors of my tab bar, so I set the (iOS 7) tab bar's barTintColor to [UIColor whiteColor].

However, when I saw the app, this tab bar wasn't as white as it should be. After some time looking through the code, the culprit was the translucency of the tab bar. After setting it to "NO", my tab bar was definitely white. However, when I pushed to my next view controller, there was a black space between my view frame in any view controller and the tab bar. setting the tab bar's translucency to YES would get rid of this problem.

I'm not sure what code I can post since I don't do anything special in viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad in my viewcontrollers (other than setting some custom properties for my feature-set)

Any suggestions? Thanks.

edit: I also tried setting a white image in place of the tab bar's background and it did the same thing even though the translucency was set to "YES" this time.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the "Extend Edges Under Bottom Bars" on your view controller in IB (tab 4)?

Comment: Are you using xibs?  Did you perhaps set a `UIToolBar` in the xib but you're actually using a `UITabBar` in your code?  They have different heights and setting the preview of the wrong one in your xib can cause this exact problem.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand correctly: you have a UITabBarController as the Initial/Root view controller of your app. And one the tabs of the UITabBarController is a UINavigationController that you are trying to push a view into?

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone. I've tried each and every suggestion provided, but to no avail, it's still shifting down. is the Extended Edges Under Bottom Bars the same as setting the edgesForExtendedLayout programatically?